# multi-client inter-process communication on Windows, VB6

Tags: windows, vb6, ipc

What is the best way for multiple client programs to
communicate with a single server program, all running
on a single Windows computer?  All written in VB6.
I'd appreciate recommendations of how you might solve
this problem.

NOTE: we are working on transition to .NET, but have to
add a capability to the V6B version before the .NET will
be ready.

The possibilities include TPC connections, named pipes,
shared memory, messages, files, and more.

A client passes the server a string as input, and the server
combines it with data known only to the server, to generate
another string  which is returned to the client.  Both strings
are only about 100 characters long.  The server is contacted
only when a new file needs to be opened, and so it is a very
low volume of communication... probably a flurry of 10 calls
within 15 seconds, followed by an hour of idle time.

But it is possible that two clients would choose about the
same time to request information.  Blocking/Locking are certainly
acceptable, as the server will be done with each request in
well under a second, and several seconds of delay is unimportant
to any of the programs.

The server's algorithm is complex, and for several reasons important
to the application should not be replicated in each helper program.
That is the reason for needing a server.

**Background:**
I am adding capability to a large existing legacy program.
This single program has several other legacy programs which
act as helpers and are run when the user makes certain
choices.  These programs are started with a shell command,
and are not just separate threads.  For instance, one helper
loads new data from a DVD drive onto the hard drive.  Another
helper just displays a chart of the current positions of
the planets.

This is a LARGE commercial legacy program that happens to be
written in VB6.  We are working to convert it and all the
helper programs to .NET, but must first release a new version
under vb6 with this added capability.  (Please don't tell me
to not use VB6, as we are already moving elsewhere.)
We need a temporary VB6 solution.

Comment: Both of the answers (from David W. and Bob Riemersma) contain excellent information.  I am not sure yet which path to take.  I gave the check mark to David's reply mainly for the reminder to keep the solution simple.  A reminder that I needed.  Thanks to you both!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a one-off upgrade release to an existing VB6 application being moved to a newer platform, I would stress keeping the modification as simple and straightforward as possible. As a result, I wouldn't go down any routes involving shared memory or anything relatively unusual.

A few options, none perfectly simple, but at least some ideas:

- Expose a COM object in the server code that performs the translation, and can be consumed by the client apps. The clients instantiate the object from the server as an out-of-process object, and let COM handle all the marshalling, etc.
- Does the server have any network awareness? VB6 doesn't do sockets/tcp natively very well, but if you've had a reason to add that in, you might be able to leverage it to perform a socket-based connection and data exchange.
- The server and client could each poll a common resource folder for the presence of a specific file that constituted inbound/outbound requests for the translation service you describe. Not very elegant, but it might be the simplest.

Just a few ideas to give you some things to think about. Hope that's helpful in some way. Good luck!

Answer (score 5):

VB6 does TCP and UDP extremely well via the standard Winsock Control component included in Pro and Enterprise Editions.  A lot of shadetree coders do seem to struggle with it though.  This is probably the most obvious route since the only other native IPC in VB6 would be COM/DCOM and DDE, however MSMQ provided excellent support for VB6 as well.

The downside of IP-based protocols is their limited namespace and resulting high probability of collisions (64K port numbers, many set aside for standard applications, ephemeral port ranges, etc.).  They're also somewhat "heavyweight" but considering the vast resources of even the oldest PCs still in service and your light traffic requirements you can ignore that in deciding.

Another option you've considered is Named Pipes.

This offers a number of advantages in your situation.  For one thing the namespace is much larger requiring only a unique name, which in the post-Win9x era can be up to 256 characters long making uniqueness fairly easy to achieve.  For another, as long as your firewalls permit "File and Print Sharing" you're all set on that front.

Also, for your application you only seem to require an RPC-style mechanism rather than arbitrary bidirectional streams or messages.  `TransactNamedPipe()` calls in your clients might be ideal.  Named Pipes work over a LAN, but within one PC they are quite fast and light weight.

While VB6 doesn't come with a Named Pipe component such a thing is fairly easy to create as long as extremely high performance isn't required.  You can use Timer-based polling in the server instead of trying to implement overlapped I/O to get asynchronicity.  I put one together a couple of years ago and have had good luck with this approach.

I published a fairly stable rendition of this a while back at [PipeRPC - RPC Over Named Pipes](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?649507-VB6-PipeRPC-RPC-Over-Named-Pipes).  There is an older and a somewhat newer version there with examples of use and documentation.  As designed, clients make "calls" passing a Byte array of request parameters and receiving back a Byte array of response results.  You can also shove Unicode Strings though with no changes, letting the compiler coerce the types.

Just one "drop in" UserControl for both clients and servers.

Looking back at this question:

> The server's algorithm is complex, and for several reasons important
>   to the application should not be replicated in each helper program.
>   That is the reason for needing a server.

If that's really the concern why not just create a shared DLL that all programs use?

Comment: I can't use a shared DLL because only the primary program has the critical data, and these data should not be embedded in a DLL.  In part, it also enforces that the helper programs never operate except in the presence of the main program.